# Using one numerical database column vs several boolean columns

Tags: sql, database-design

So I have a db with a table user.
The user can be moderator, owner, or nothing of both, or both.

I can design this with to booleans isModerator and isOwner
which would become to db columns

Or I could create a column hasUserRight
with 1 for moderator
2 for owner

What is the better approach to design the db with it and why?

Comment: "What is better" is clearly an indication of an opinion-based answer, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there are only the two roles, both your solutions will work. But I agree with the others that one column per role would be easier to read and should be preferred hence.

However, problems occur when having to add a third role. If this is something that you know for sure will never happen, okay. But if it can happen, you should think of the consequences. Let's add a new role "revisor" and let's say that a revisor must be a moderator.

**Solution 1: isModerator, isOwner**

Add isRevisor. All written code will run as before. You can add code for isRevisor. Add a check constraint so that isRevisor cannot be set true if isModerator is false. Done.

=> database (DDL) changes only

**Solution 2: hasUserRight 0=none, 1=moderator, 2=owner, 3=all=moderator+owner and a constraint** hasUserRight in (0,1,2,3)

(I wouldn't recommend this, because it's not obvious what the different values mean.)

You need more values: 4=moderator+revisor, 5=all=moderator+owner+revisor (or better 3=all=moderator+owner+revisor and 5=moderator+owner?). Your code will be broken, because hasUserRight in (1,3) does no longer select all moderators. You will have to fix the code. Change the contraint to hasUserRight in (0,1,2,3,4,5).

=> code changes + database (DDL) changes

**Solution 3: hasUserRight 0=none, 1=moderator, 2=owner, 3=all=moderator+owner and a table UserRight holding the values 0 to 3 along with an explnational text.**

Again, you need more values: 4=moderator+revisor, 5=all=moderator+owner+revisor (or better 3=all=moderator+owner+revisor and 5=moderator+owner?). Add them to your role table. Your code will be broken, because hasUserRight in (1,3) does no longer select all moderators. You will have to fix the code. No need to change any constraint; the foreign key only allows valid values.

=> only code changes

**Solution 4: a table role and a bridge table user_role**

Simply insert the new role in table role. Add entries to table user_role if you like. Done. All you need is inserts. Your dbms cannot guarantee however that each revisor is a moderator; you will have to care about this yourself.

=> no changes at all to code or database (DDL)

As you see solution 2 and 3 (hasUserRight) are bad. Decide for either solution 1 or 4, whatever you prefer and find more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You are clearly talking about user roles, you a second option is using flags for each role. This will limit you to a certain number of roles and is not easy to understand. The first option is not normalized, adding functionality will be more work etc.

Adding a table with roles and a userrole table will give you a more generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

An issue arises with your second solution. What if the user is an owner and a moderator? You would have to assign a fourth numerical value for that situation assuming that `0` would represent neither owner nor moderator. Even if this layout was well documented, it still would not be intuitive.

Your first solution is much cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: Yes, absolutely correct.